# How can I get the base URI in AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I get the base URI in a Google AppEngine app written in Python? I'm using the webapp framework.

e.g.

```
http://example.appspot.com/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to parse `self.request.url` is not with a regular expression, but with Python standard library's [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urlparse#module-urlparse) module:

```
import urlparse

...

o = urlparse.urlparse(self.request.url)
```

Object `o` will be an instance of the `ParseResult` class with string-valued fields such as `o.scheme` (probably `http`;-) and `o.netloc` (`'example.appspot.com'` in your case).  You can put some of the strings back together again with the [urlparse.urlunparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urlparse#urlparse.urlunparse) function from the same module, e.g.

```
s = urlparse.urlunparse((o.scheme, o.netloc, '', '', '', ''))
```

which would give you in `s` the string `'http://example.appspot.com'` in this case.

Comment: Or you could just use, eg, self.request.host_url, self.request.host, etc, which already have these parts split out for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find your app ID, you can get that from the [environment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Environment) without having to parse the current URL. The environment variable is `APPLICATION_ID`

You can also use this to find the current version (`CURRENT_VERSION_ID`), auth domain (which will let you know whether you're running on appspot.com, `AUTH_DOMAIN`) and whether you're running on the local development server or in production (`SERVER_SOFTWARE`).

So to get the full base URL, try something like this:

```
import os

def get_base_url():
    if os.environ[AUTH_DOMAIN] == "gmail.com":
        app_id = os.environ[APPLICATION_ID]
        return "http://" + app_id + ".appspot.com"
    else:
        return "http://" + os.environ[AUTH_DOMAIN]
```

**edit:** `AUTH_DOMAIN` contains the custom domain, no need to include the app ID.

This will return the current version's base URL even if you're not accessing the current version, or if you visit the current version using a URL like `http://current-version.latest.app_id.appspot.com` (unlike URL-parsing methods)

Comment: This assumes the app is being accessed on appspot, and will fail horribly if your base URL is on a Google Apps domain.

Comment: @Wooble that's what the `AUTH_DOMAIN` bit is -- if it's not being hosted on appspot.com, the `AUTH_DOMAIN` is the custom domain where it is hosted.

Comment: An app can use Google auth but still be served from another domain name; the AUTH_DOMAIN envvar will still get set to "gmail.com"